# margin pushing parent element instead of itself

Tags: html, css, margin

Hey guys I have a little problem with my css and I can't figure out why it's doing it. The block is placed inside the container it should push itself away from the container position but instead it pushed the whole container down? Can someone explain what's going wrong? Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/aFcZa/

Html

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="block">
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background-color: black;
}

#container {
width: 70%;
height: 500px;
background-color: green;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#block {
width: 300px;
background-color: red;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/aFcZa/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to float child element, or change display property to change it's position inside parent element.

**Floating**

*HTML*

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

*SCSS*

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
}

.wrap {
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .content {
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFLLW/)

**Display**

Or just change display:inline-block for child element

*HTML same code*

*SCSS*

```
...
.content {
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        display: inline-block;
    }...
```

Answer (score 2):

It pushes the container down, because the `#block` element is IN the `#container` element.

If you change your html markup like this:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
```

the `#block` element will push itself away from the `#container` element.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aFcZa/1/)

**UPDATE:**

If you want to keep your HTML structure, just give `#block` the following css: `position: absolute;`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aFcZa/4/)

Comment: Yeah but I want it to be in the container element. I want the margin to be applied inside of the container but instead it applies the margin to the whole container?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. In that case give `#block` the ccs: `position: absolute;`.

Answer (score 0):

An `overflow:auto` to `#container` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Margin bleeds outside of it's container unless you specify padding on the parent container.  Give the parent 1px padding on the edge that is adjacent to your child element's margin